Retrieve a flight offer by ID with Amadeus's API
My early-stage startup is aiming to create a modern airfare booking experience, akin to Shopify's checkout. Our express checkout button lives on the airline's website after the traveller has selected the flight itinerary, fare class and passengers. We have a requirement to populate flight offer information from a single ID, that is passed by the airline as a query param in our URL. So that we can complete the rest of the booking, i.e. collect passenger information, add ancillaries and collect payment.
Is this flow possible with Amadeus's API?
So far from what I have read in the API documentation is that you always have to start with flight search followed by checking the fare price, and finally creating the order. So not sure if an offer can be queried by its ID, or even by the flight number.
Thanks in advance,
Brian
